# Split matrix to a list of matrix by vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I am trying to split my matrix to a `list` by unique value in vector. Vector will have as many values as is in each column in matrix.
Here is an example:

```
 #matrix
 b <- cbind(c(2,2,1,0), c(2,2,1,5), c(2,2,5,6))
 #vector
 a <- c(5,5,4,1)
 #??
 #my outcome should looks like
 v <- list(cbind(c(2,2), c(2,2), c(2,2)), c(1,1,5), c(0,5,6))
```

so basically, I want to split my matrix into multiple matrices by rows by unique values in a vector. More specifically, my vector is sorted from highest value to lowest value and I need to keep it in a list! As you can see in the example, `v[[1]]` is matrix for `unique(a)[1]` and so on.

Comment: Unclear how `c(2,2)` can be the list representing unique values from the row `c(2,2,2)` -- obviously the unique value is just `2`; if you really want just unique values: `apply(b, 1, unique)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lapply(split(seq_along(a), a), #split indices by a
       function(m, ind) m[ind,], m = b)[order(unique(a))]
#$`5`
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    2    2
#[2,]    2    2    2
#
#$`4`
#[1] 1 1 5
#
#$`1`
#[1] 0 5 6
```

Comment: This is extraordinary briliant! Thx a lot!